# Prevent emacsclient from blocking other instances

Tags: emacsclient

I use emacs in the terminal, typically with many emacs instances running at once in different tabs. This is a perfect use case for emacsclient, but it has always had various glitches that have stopped me from using it. In particular, sometimes one client will "block" the other, preventing it from doing anything. It looks like things work better in emacs 24.4, but it still happens.

For instance, if I start two clients, and run `M-g M-g` in one, to get the "Goto line" entry, the other client will be completely locked down until I quit in the first one.

I am using emacs 24.4 compiled without windowed support in Mac OS X 10.10 (in iTerm 2). I can reproduce it by starting `emacs --daemon -Q`. If you want the exact emacs binary I am using, download [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) for OS X and run `conda install -c asmeurer emacs`.

Comment: FWIW, I've since given up on trying to run multiple emacsclients at once. Instead, I start one emacs server per terminal tab using `--socket-name=emacs-$TTY` (see https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/emacs-server-start for the exact script I use). Since I only use a handful of terminal tabs and never close them, this works well for me.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't "prevent emacsclient from blocking other [emacsclient] instances", because that's not what's happening.

emacsclient isn't running any elisp at all, so it's not the cause of the blockage. The Emacs **server** is running the elisp code, and Emacs is single-threaded -- so if the server thread is blocked then none of the clients will be receiving any output. There's nothing that a client can do about that.

You can, as mentioned in the comments, run multiple independent servers side by side. The simplest way to do this is via the `--daemon=NAME` command line argument:

```
emacs --daemon=foo
emacs --daemon=bar
emacsclient --socket-name=foo
emacsclient --socket-name=bar
```

or short-cut it to:

```
emacsclient -a "" --socket-name=foo
emacsclient -a "" --socket-name=bar
```

Comment: I guess this is workable. I can add `export TTY=$(basename \`tty\`)` in my bash profile and use `--socket-name=$TTY`.

Comment: A disadvantage here is that I no longer get any shared state if I open the same file in different instances. I would still very much appreciate an actual solution to this problem.

Comment: Even with this solution, emacsclient (or the server, whatever) will still sometimes completely block all clients, forcing me to find the PID for the server process and `kill -9` it.

Comment: And just now I've got a server that even when I kill it, every time it restarts it immediately blocks, making it unusable.

Comment: There is certainly no solution to Emacs being single-threaded, short of re-writing it to be multi-threaded (and there are many good reasons why this has never happened).

Comment: I don't follow why being single threaded means it has to block sometimes. It doesn't always block, even when I am editing the same buffer in two different clients

Comment: Emacs has a command loop which can execute one command at a time. When you are "editing", each command (e.g. inserting a character) takes very little time. When Emacs is prompting you for input, it is in the middle of executing a command, and it cannot continue the command until you have provided the necessary input. (Maybe. This isn't the whole story, and I've really never delved into this part of Emacs, so I might be incorrect; but it should at least indicate how regular editing is a different scenario).

Comment: It's still locking up even with a server for each terminal session sometimes. I've asked a new question for it http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3370/emacs-daemon-frozen-when-started-with-emacsclient-file

Comment: This is not quite correct.  Yes, everything runs on the server, and yes, the server is single threaded, but there is no *technical* reason for the minibuffer to block the server loop.  You can see this in action by switching from the mini buffer to a different buffer while leaving the mini buffer open (with a partial command in it).  There's got to be some internal lock getting set which blocks other clients (or the server itself if using `server-start`) while a minibuffer is open (focused or not).  I'll see if I can find it and defadvice my way around it.

Answer (score 3):

Got it!  Good news is it works perfectly to have the minibuffer active in one window and type in another*.  Bad news is it requires recompiling `emacs`, as it's the C-implementation of read_minibuf which forces single-kboard.  It's probably possible to reimplement the minibuffer largely in elisp, intercepting *most* calls to it, but that would be somewhat complex...

Anyway, with emacs-26, the line to comment is `src/minibuf.c:480`,

`temporarily_switch_to_single_kboard (XFRAME (mini_frame));`

*I've tested it *some*, no promises it won't break things in subtle ways. Also note that the minibuffer uses a single, global input state, so opening the mini buffer closes any mini buffers opened in other frames. If you enable recursive-minibuffers, you do get your partial command back when the other person is done, but there's still likely to be some odd behaviour.  Also, things like `find-file` use `switch_to_single_kboard` too.

I'll probably follow up on the mailing list to see if this can get turned into a proper customizable variable, possibly disabling all `switch_to_single_kboard` calls, as it's a must for sharing an emacs instance on a joint project.

If you want to disable single-keyboard mode *everywhere*, insert `return;` on a new line at `src/keyboard.c:883`.

As requested, a diff...

```
*** src/minibuf.c       2020-02-20 17:27:13.472345220 -0800
--- src.orig/minibuf.c  2020-02-20 17:26:20.164343599 -0800
***************
*** 478,482 ****
      Fraise_frame (mini_frame);

<   //temporarily_switch_to_single_kboard (XFRAME (mini_frame));

    /* We have to do this after saving the window configuration
--- 478,482 ----
      Fraise_frame (mini_frame);

>   temporarily_switch_to_single_kboard (XFRAME (mini_frame));

        /* We have to do this after saving the window configuration
```

And the other diff

```
*** src/keyboard.c      2020-02-20 17:27:01.452344855 -0800
--- src.orig/keyboard.c 2020-02-20 17:26:15.040343443 -0800
***************
*** 881,885 ****
  temporarily_switch_to_single_kboard (struct frame *f)
  {
<   return false;
    bool was_locked = single_kboard;
--- 881,884 ----
```

Comment: That sounds like something I won't be trying :)  Could you please show actual diffs in your answer?  Only showing line numbers isn't nearly as useful.

Comment: Note that this produces poor results in emacs-27 (and probably later), since partial commands are stored (and completed) globally.  Then again, that's an issue even without unlocking multi-keyboard mode in the minibuffer.

Comment: A year later, I've found and patched the emacs-27+ bug that breaks multiple keyboards. IfI ever hear back from the FSF about my copyright assignment I'll even get that fix included...  So far, crickets.

Comment: Awesome; cheers.  They're normally fairly responsive, so if you haven't heard anything within a few days, definitely chase that up (either directly, or on the emacs-devel mailing list).  I'm sure that someone will sort you out.

Comment: What is the bug that breaks multiple keyboards on 27+?

Answer (score 1):

I frequently run into the problem of emacsclient instances being blocked, sometimes accompanied by an error message like `"*ERROR*: Terminal 2 is locked, cannot read from it"`. A solution for unblocking it is to run:

```bash
emacsclient -e '(top-level)'
```

The problem and solution are discussed in more detail in https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/admin/notes/multi-tty and have to do with a session being stuck in a minibuffer prompt or recursive editing mode.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.sx! Anyone else dealing with recursive editing and so on might find this Emacs Elements video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD8myoNYnss -- it's a nice intro to the various "get me out of here" things in emacs.