# emacs --daemon frozen when started with emacsclient file

Tags: emacsclient, daemon, terminal-emacs

This is somewhat of a follow up to [Prevent emacsclient from blocking other instances](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/prevent-emacsclient-from-blocking-other-instances).

I am using `emacsclient -a '' -nw --socket-name=$TTY` where `TTY=$(basename tty)`. I use emacs in the terminal and this gives a unique daemon for each terminal session.

If I start the daemon by running `emacsclient` with no arguments, it starts and everything works fine. However, if I start it by running `emacsclient file`, it locks down. It opens the scratch buffer and then gets frozen. The only way to fix it is to `kill -9` the daemon process and to restart it without opening a file.

I am using emacs 24.4 compiled with `--without-x` with Mac OS X in iTerm 2. You can get the exact build of emacs I am using with [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/) `conda install -c asmeurer emacs`.

**EDIT**

I found after disabling flyspell (commenting out [these lines](https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles/blob/29f6c3ae344a784cb536ddbc07bf53b3a234bbd2/.emacs#L614-L637) from my .emacs), it fixes it. It still hangs on the scratch buffer for a few seconds, but then goes to the file. I suspect it has something to do with starting the hunspell process.

Comment: A workaround would be to always start an emacs daemon with each terminal session (i.e., in the bash profile). This would slow down the terminal start time, though, and would lead to many unused servers.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Can you detail an exact sequence of commands to recreate the problem, including the value for $TTY in that instance, and confirming the versions of both emacs and emacsclient (check both `emacsclient --version` from the command line, and `M-x emacs-version` from within emacs, and confirm they match).

Comment: Same thing here, can't replicate issue using GNU Emacs 24.3.1, emacsclient 24.3

Comment: I added some info on how to reproduce. A typical server name is `ttys004`.

Comment: How have you ruled out init file issues?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test that. `emacsclient` doesn't seem to support the `-Q` option.

Comment: The init file is evaluated run when the *server* starts, so you'd run `emacs --daemon -Q`

Comment: But it doesn't happen if I start the server first.

Comment: @asmeurermore your init out of the way before you trigger the start of the daemon with emacsclient.

Comment: Ah, so it does seem to be related to something in my .emacs.

Comment: My .emacs is at https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs. I'll try bisecting it, but I have really no idea what would be causing this, so I'm shooting in the dark.

Comment: I bisected the issue to flyspell (with hunspell). See my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a reasonable workaround. First, add a script to your `PATH` with

```
#!/bin/sh
export TTY=$(basename `tty`)

emacs --daemon="emacs-$TTY"
emacsclient -n -nw --socket-name="emacs-$TTY"
emacsclient -nw --socket-name="emacs-$TTY" "$@"
```

called `emacs-server-start`. Then start emacsclient with `emacsclient -a 'emacs-server-start' -nw --socket-name=emacs-$TTY` (I have `e` aliased to this in my bash configuration).

You basically are creating a custom "start emacs server" alternate editor for `emacsclient -a`, since `emacsclient -a ''` doesn't work.  Saving this to a file is necessary because the argument to `-a` must be a single command (i.e., `emacsclient -a 'emacs --daemon'` does not work).

The extra `emacsclient -n`, which causes emacsclient to start and immediately close with no file, is there because otherwise emacs will sometimes still freeze at startup.