# If an emacsclient has an open minibuffer when it's closed, it freezes everything

Tags: minibuffer, daemon

I use `emacs --daemon` for everything, which means I frequently have several different instances of `emacsclient` running at a time. I've noticed that if I execute an action which opens a minibuffer, it freezes all of the other clients, as detailed in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/prevent-emacsclient-from-blocking-other-instances). This is annoying but it's not so bad if I can find the instance of `emacsclient` which has the open minibuffer and close the buffer.

But if I inadvertently close the terminal running emacsclient, *while that client had a minibuffer open*, then I can't close the minibuffer, and the end result is that every client is frozen and I have to completely shut down my emacs server, which is an enormous pain, due to having to reopen a ton of files and long-running `ansi-term` sessions, not to mention potentially losing work.

I don't know of a workaround for this situation. `kill -USR2` works for some cases of frozen emacs, but doesn't seem to work for this. I tried `kill -HUP` but that just ended up nuking the whole server, which is.... not good at all? Help!

Comment: Does `C-]` from any of the clients unblock the server so that you can continue?

Comment: @NickD sorry for the slow reply -- `C-]` seems to have no effect :(